# ReactJS - Nothing was returned from render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

> Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

I Have an issue related to this message. This is my component that causes the error:

```
import React from 'react';
import Thumbnail from './Thumbnail';

const AlbumList = ({ results }) => {
  let collections = [];
  let albums = { };

Object.values(results).map((item, i) => {
  if(!collections.includes(item.collectionId)) {
    collections.push(item.collectionId);
    albums[i] = {id: item.collectionId, cover: item.artworkUrl100}
  }
return albums;
});

Object.values(albums).forEach(element => {
 return (
  <Thumbnail source={element.cover} />
  )
 })
}

export default AlbumList;
```

Thumbnail is just a basic Component like:

```
import React from 'react';

const Thumbnail = ({source}) =>  {
  return(
    <div>
      <img src={source} alt="album cover"/>
    </div>
 )
}

export default Thumbnail;
```

I've been looking for the error like an hour or so.
What am I missing?

Comment: You are using `.map()` and `.forEach` incorrectly. With `.map()`, you expect to get something back from it, while with `.forEach()`, you expect to do something in it.

Comment: What do you think that the return value of  AlbumList function is? There's no return statement in the scope of the AlbumList function. forEach callback functions don't need to return anything.

Comment: Duplicate of [JavaScript: Difference between .forEach() and .map()](/q/34426458/4642212) and [What does `return` keyword mean inside `forEach` function?](/q/34653612/4642212). This isn’t really related to React.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that `map` returns a list while `forEach` returns undefined.

You don't return anything from your functional Component Plus `forEach` does not return anything, instead change it to map.

Also you need to set the unique key to Thumbnail component in loop

```
return Object.values(albums).map((element, index) => {
 return (
  <Thumbnail key={"Key-"+index} source={element.cover} />
  )
 })
```

I would suggest to read this article [map vs. forEach](https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f)

Comment: I updated your answer with adding key to Thumbanail component otherwise only one will be rendered