# Using .map on a component causes component to return "Nothing was returned from render...." error

Tags: reactjs

I am getting the `Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null` from my react component. It was working fine, then I added a `.map` to duplicate the component and started getting the error. I have looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741247/nothing-was-returned-from-render-this-usually-means-a-return-statement-is-missi), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53250253/reactjs-nothing-was-returned-from-render), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51702627/reactjs-nothing-was-returned-from-render/51702662), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57300009/react-error-nothing-was-returned-from-render), but didn't find my answer

```
const AdvisorData = ({weekListForAllAdvisorsOfState}) => {
    const data = usePreloadedQuery(query, queryReference);
    let {forecast} = data
    forecast.map((ind, index) => {
        return (
          <TableRow key={ind.referralCode}>
              <AdvisorTableCell>
                  <pw-subtitle size="small" color="black">{ind.referralCode}</pw-subtitle>
                  <div style={{ flexBasis: "100%" }} />
                  <pw-subtitle size="small" color="grey">{ind.postalCode}</pw-subtitle>
              </AdvisorTableCell>
          </TableRow>
        )
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try in this way?

```
const AdvisorData = ({weekListForAllAdvisorsOfState}) => {
    const data = usePreloadedQuery(query, queryReference);
    let {forecast} = data
        return (
        forecast.map((ind, index) => {
          <TableRow key={ind.referralCode}>
              <AdvisorTableCell>
                  <pw-subtitle size="small" color="black">{ind.referralCode}</pw-subtitle>
                  <div style={{ flexBasis: "100%" }} />
                  <pw-subtitle size="small" color="grey">{ind.postalCode}</pw-subtitle>
              </AdvisorTableCell>
              {weekListForAllAdvisorsOfState}
          </TableRow>
        )
    }})
```